# ¿Como puedo obtener el valor de un campo con javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5

El problema es que no me retorna la función que he creado.
me da este error y no tengo muy claro porque
Uncaught TypeError: Document.getElementByid is not a function
    at validar.js:2
Este es el codigo:

```
const n_tarjeta = Document.getElementByid("numero_tarjeta");

form.addEventListener("submit"), e=>{

    e.preventDefault();

    if (n_tarjeta.value.length<16) {

        alert("Numero de tarjeta invalido");


    }

}
```

Comment: Document va en minúscula

Comment: Como es un error tipográfico es seguro que tu pregunta termine cerrada

Comment: Aunque la ponga en minúscula me sigue marcando el mismo error

Comment: Sigue la sintaxis como está aquí https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Comment: Es que también te falta ahora pasar a mayúscula la i de id

Comment: Y al addEventListener tienes que pasarle dos argumentos así que te seguirá fallando.

Comment: gracias, ya lo solucione :)

Comment: Deberías poner como lo has solucionado, ya que la intención de esta comunidad es dar soluciones a problemas concretos. Si a alguien le pasa lo mismo que a ti debería poder encontrar su solución aquí.

Answer (score 0):

El evento submit se activa en el elemento `<form>` en sí, y no en ningún `<button>` o `<input type="submit">` dentro de él por lo que hay que añadir el listener al elemento form. El código correcto sería así:

```
const n_tarjeta = document.getElementById("numero_tarjeta");
    document.getElementById('form').addEventListener("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (n_tarjeta.value.length<16) {
        alert("Numero de tarjeta invalido");
    }
})
```

Comment: Hola Javi, aunque esta respuesta puede servir para resolver el problema expuesto en la pregunta, ha sido reportada como de baja calidad por la comunidad por su extensión y contenido. Deberías editar tu respuesta para añadir una descripción de los cambios que realizaste y por qué solucionan el problema. Lee [answer] para más información.